# How do I use FFMPEG with filter_complex to combine/join a full folder of 40+ audio files into one long mp3?

Tags: bash, ffmpeg

I have a full directory of 40-50 audio files that I am trying to "concat" into one long mp3.

I was able to do this just testing around with 2 files using the command shown below, but I need an easy way to do this with a script that I can make if I have a folder of many files with complicated file names.  This is something I'm going to be doing frequently so if I had a script or something I could use quickly that would be most helpful.

```
ffmpeg -i a.webm -i b.webm -filter_complex "[0:a] [1:a] concat=n=2:v=0:a=1 [a]" -map [a] -c:a mp3 testfull.mp3
```

Comment: Did the answer work for you?

Comment: no, because the list of files will be variable and much longer than just 2...

Comment: The answer should work with just about any number of input files.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to use the [concat demuxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#concat), but all inputs must be the same format and have the same attributes (sample rate, sample format, channel layout).

```
printf "file '%s'\n" *.webm > input.txt
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i input.txt -map 0:a output.mp3
```

`-safe 0` is only needed if your input file names contain special characters.